# Unable to create ionic 3 project with ionic 6 cli

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic6, ionic-cli

I have old ionic 3 project which i want into in my machine but its not working here i am creating simple ionic 3 project using below command

`ionic start Ionic3Project blank --type=ionic-angular`

It throws lot of error

[image]

Here is details of ionic-cli and angular-cli in case needed

[image]

[image]

Thanks for reading :-)

Comment: It says that neither a Ionic Framework or app-scripts is installed, you dont think that could be an issue? It also says "Angular: <error>" and typescript <error> . Maybe try and reinstall?

Comment: i was inside ionic 3 project thats why it says app-script not installed.
All things works well with ionic 5/6 projects so i think this is not an issue.

Comment: why are you trying to create ionic 3 project???

Comment: i have old ionic 3 project which i need to run to check features, i tried npm install inside ionic 3 project but it not worked.
No i decided to create blank ionic 3 project and simple copy pages and install plugin which i want to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally that guy helped me!

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4901

Hope someone will save time with this solution.